# Push Notification OneSignal by a Firebase DB

Tags: typescript, ionic3, onesignal

I want to send a notification to all clients when a user push or delete something to the firebase database. Obviously all clients interact with the same database. I searched all things possible and I finded that OneSignal can be a possible solution. Someone cuold explain if this is possible and how I can implement it? Because I already tried to build something with OneSignal but I can't understand how I can push a notification only when my database is modified.

PS I'm working with Ionic 3, on VSCode.

Comment: You can trigger notifications from your JS code when the users are interacting with the database without other frameworks. Please complete your answer so I can provide a question.
Do you use any plugin(fcm, push plugin)? 
Would you like to send a push notifications to all users when a user adds/removes something from the database, or to a specific group of users that are interested in that change? Thanks

Comment: I want to push a notification to all users and it's a simple notification like added something or remove something else from the database. I tried some plugins but without any results. It's a simple stuff, and your idea it's not to bad. How i can push notification when someone interact with the db?

Comment: Yes, you can send a push notification when someone interact with the db. If you expand your question I can give you a more in-depth solution but you can simply use the phonegap-plugin-push or cordova-plugin-firebase following this tutorial https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821.